# How I can insert label and field value in the same TextBox, in VisualStudio?

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm beginner in Visual Studio.

In a **TextBox** in *PrecisionDesign* how should I do to insert label and FIeldValue ?

I want a lookLike this result:

> *MyLabel: fieldValue*

I used this code, in *Expression properties*:

```
="MyLabel" & Fields!M_myField.Value
```

but it does not work.

Why is that so?

Comment: Is M_myField a numeric? If so you need to cast it as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics AX Labels are named with an '@' sign, a code for the label file, and a number. For example one of the system labels for the text "Item" is `@SYS7407`. That is the code you need to use the label in forms and reports.

In SSRS, the expression to use a label is `=Labels!<insert label code here>`. Therefore, for your situation, the expression for the field would look like this (using my item label):

```
=Labels!@SYS7407 + ': ' + Fields!M_myField.Value
```

If you actually meant a static string for labeling a field, then you would just use the plus sign for concatenation instead of the ampersand in your example:

```
="MyLabel: " + Fields!M_myField.Value
```